JQuery script to move element around the border of a circle on mouse move
I'm almost there with this -
Looking to create a small circle that moves around the border of a larger circle on mouse move. I have the following but the small circle doesn't stay within the confines of the parent outer circle, although the movement is correct.
Codepen: https://codepen.io/Katharine-Mills/pen/jOoVJqa
Tried the following:
The result was that the small inner circle moves to the bottom right of the outer circle rather than following along the border.


$(document).ready(function() {
  const outerCircle = $('#outerCircle');
  const innerCircle = $('#innerCircle');
  const outerCircleRadius = outerCircle.width() / 2;
  const innerCircleRadius = innerCircle.width() / 2;

  // Update inner circle position based on mouse movement on the screen
  $(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
    const containerX = outerCircle.offset().left;
    const containerY = outerCircle.offset().top;
    const centerX = containerX + outerCircleRadius;
    const centerY = containerY + outerCircleRadius;
    const mouseX = event.clientX;
    const mouseY = event.clientY;

    // Calculate the angle between the mouse and the center of the outer circle
    const angle = Math.atan2(mouseY - centerY, mouseX - centerX);

    // Calculate the position of the inner circle on the outer circle's circumference
    const innerCircleX = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * (outerCircleRadius - innerCircleRadius);
    const innerCircleY = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * (outerCircleRadius - innerCircleRadius);

    // Set the position of the inner circle
    innerCircle.css({
      left: innerCircleX - innerCircleRadius,
      top: innerCircleY - innerCircleRadius
    });
  });
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.outer-circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="circle outer-circle" id="outerCircle">
    <div class="inner-circle" id="innerCircle"></div>
  </div>
</div>




Looks like just some funky math on the positioning calculation - I've repaired it in the snippet here. The last two calculations in the CSS statement should have been adding outerCircleRadius instead of subtracting innerCircleRadius.
It's been adjusted to follow the path of the outer circle, if you want it to stay fully inside the outer circle instead, you can adjust the two position calculations back to adjust for it:
const innerCircleX = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * (outerCircleRadius - innerCircleRadius);
const innerCircleY = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * (outerCircleRadius - innerCircleRadius);

Otherwise, here is the version where it follows the path of the large circle - it shows as cut off due to the overflow hidden but wasn't sure if that was the desired effect.


$(document).ready(function() {
  const outerCircle = $('#outerCircle');
  const innerCircle = $('#innerCircle');
  const outerCircleRadius = outerCircle.width() / 2;
  const innerCircleRadius = innerCircle.width() / 2;

  // Update inner circle position based on mouse movement on the screen
  $(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
    const containerX = outerCircle.offset().left;
    const containerY = outerCircle.offset().top;
    const centerX = containerX + outerCircleRadius;
    const centerY = containerY + outerCircleRadius;
    const mouseX = event.clientX;
    const mouseY = event.clientY;

    // Calculate the angle between the mouse and the center of the outer circle
    const angle = Math.atan2(mouseY - centerY, mouseX - centerX);

    // Calculate the position of the inner circle on the outer circle's circumference
    const innerCircleX = Math.cos(angle) * (outerCircleRadius);
    const innerCircleY = Math.sin(angle) * (outerCircleRadius);

    // Set the position of the inner circle
    innerCircle.css({ left: innerCircleX + outerCircleRadius, top: innerCircleY + outerCircleRadius });
  });
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.outer-circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="circle outer-circle" id="outerCircle">
    <div class="inner-circle" id="innerCircle"></div>
  </div>
</div>



